# Search is not working in orocrm 2.0

Tags: orocrm

In orocrm  i created some contact and search them through search which is given in top of navigation. But it show "no match found". Please reply.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have running message queue consumer all the time to have search and other functionality working properly. Please follow the documentation to know how https://www.orocrm.com/documentation/current/book/installation#activating-background-tasks